# Obfuscating dump files

Tags: windbg

Like in [my previous question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3874/removing-personal-data-from-dump-file), I want to make some dump files available for learning dump analysis and reverse engineering.

To organize my example programs from which I create the dumps, I give them meaningful names. However, that usually means that I can type `|` in WinDbg to find out what it demonstrates. I want to remove that workaround.

> Is it possible to obfuscate a dump file, i.e. rename my modules to a random name while keeping the dump itself intact? (not renaming the system modules of course)
>
> Are there already any tools which could help me accomplishing this task? Something which breaks the dump into its streams and can reassemble streams would be nice.

I am looking for

- dumps of a program which has dependencies on other modules.

I am **not** looking for

- the simple single executable case. I can rename the executable before creating the dump as part of my build script.
- obfuscation of .NET methods. I can obfuscate the .NET code as part of my build script.

Answer (score 2):

if you are fine with hexediting the stream is documented in dbghelp.inc that comes with windbg sdk

use `dumpchk` on the dmp file and find the `rva of the ModuleList stream`

if it is say 0x294

you will see the `_MINIDUMP_MODULE_LIST` located there ignoring the first dword which is Number of modules `_MINIDUMP_MODULE` follows  use `sizeof (_MINIDUMP_MODULE)` to navigate to the next module 
one of the field in each module struct is an rva to the module name

the format of module name is

```
ulong32 size of string
wstr  name
```

you can hexedit the name there

```
C:\>dumpchk foo.dmp | grep ModuleListStream
Loading dump file foo.dmp
Stream 1: type ModuleListStream (4), size 000004A8, RVA 00000294


C:\>xxd -s 0x294 -l 0x70 -g 4 foo.dmp
0000294: 0b000000 00000001 00000000 00f00100  ................
00002a4: fcd70100 10847d3b 660a0000 bd04effe  ......};f.......
00002b4: 00000100 01000500 0000280a 01000500  ..........(.....
00002c4: 0000280a 3f000000 00000000 04000400  ..(.?...........
00002d4: 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
00002e4: 19000000 22110000 00000000 00000000  ...."...........
00002f4: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................

C:\>xxd -s 0xa66 -l 0x20 -g 1 foo.dmp
0000a66: 10 00 00 00 63 00 61 00 6c 00 63 00 2e 00 65 00  ....c.a.l.c...e.
0000a76: 78 00 65 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 6e 00 74 00 64 00  x.e.......n.t.d.

C:\>echo pathched with hxd
pathched with hxd

C:\>xxd -s 0xa66 -l 0x20 -g 1 foo.dmp
0000a66: 10 00 00 00 64 00 61 00 6c 00 63 00 2e 00 65 00  ....d.a.l.c...e.
0000a76: 78 00 65 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 6e 00 74 00 64 00  x.e.......n.t.d.

C:\>cdb -z foo.dmp

0:000> |
.  0    id: 548 examine name: dalc.exe
0:000>
```

here is how to delete peb from the dump file created with .dump /marR

```
C:\>cdb -c ".dump /marR /u c:\foo.dmp;q" calc

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.dump /marR /u c:\foo.dmp;q'
Creating c:\foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
quit:


C:\>ls -lh foo*
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0 14M 2014-03-22 13:38 foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0
.dmp

C:\>cdb  -c "!peb;q" -z foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '!peb;q'
PEB at 7ffde000
    InheritedAddressSpace:    No
    ReadImageFileExecOptions: No
    BeingDebugged:            Yes
    ImageBaseAddress:         01000000
    Ldr                       001a1ea0


C:\>dumpchk foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp | grep -i peb
Loading dump file foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp
PEB at 7ffde000

C:\>dumpchk foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp | grep -i 7ffde000
Loading dump file foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp
      62 00DA7ACE    7ffde000   00001000
PEB at 7ffde000

C:\>xxd -s 0xda7ace -l 0x10 -g 1 foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp
0da7ace: 00 00 01 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 01 a0 1e 1a 00  ................

C:\> filled 0x1000 bytes with 0 with hxd (selct block -> fill)

C:\>xxd -s 0xda7ace -l 0x10 -g 1 foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp
0da7ace: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................


C:\>cdb  -c "!peb;q" -z foo_0fa4_2014-03-22_13-38-25-062_00a0.dmp


0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '!peb;q'
PEB at 7ffde000
    InheritedAddressSpace:    No
    ReadImageFileExecOptions: No
    BeingDebugged:            No
    ImageBaseAddress:         00000000
    Ldr                       00000000
    *** unable to read Ldr table at 00000000
    SubSystemData:     00000000
    ProcessHeap:       00000000
    ProcessParameters: 00000000
    *** unable to read process parameters
quit:
```